# Need help taking average of this array (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner at VBA, so if someone could give me a clear explanation it would be great.
I wrote the following with the intent of taking a weekly average (each row) for none empty cells. It's giving me an error msg at the w_avg(i) step.

```
Sub weekly_avg()

    Dim w_avg(19) As Long
    Dim MyRange(19, 6) As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Cells(1, 11) = "Weekly Avg by VBA"
    Cells(1, 11).Columns.AutoFit

    For i = 0 To 19
       For j = 0 To 6
           MyRange(i, j) = Cells(i + 2, j + 3)
                If Not Cells(i + 2, j + 3) = 0 Then
                   w_avg(i)=Worksheets("sheet1").WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(MyRange(i, 0),MyRange(i, j)))
                    Cells(i + 2, 11).Value = w_avg(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here

1. `WorksheetFunction` is a method of the `Application` object (and is actually not needed)
2. `Range(MyRange(i, 0),MyRange(i, j))` won't work, as `MyRange(...)` values are numbers. (`Cells(MyRange(i, 0),MyRange(i, j))` might work)
3. You are repeating the same calculation on each iteration of `For j`
4. Too many magic numbers
5. Output is written to the Active Sheet. This may be your intent, but it is always better to be explicit
6. If your range is large (1000's of rows) you might consider converting to use a variant Array to speed things up

Try this instead

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OutputColumn As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells(1, 11) = "Weekly Avg by VBA"
    ws.Cells(1, 11).Columns.AutoFit

    ' Get a reference to the data range
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:I21")
    ' Specify output column relative to data range
    OutputColumn = rng.Columns.Count + 2

    With Application
        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            rng.Cells(i, OutputColumn).Value = _
              .AverageIf(rng.Rows(i), "<>0")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for being concise. I see some of my mistakes you mentioned. To follow up with your solution, what's the advantage of defining rng as Range rather than Array, other than that it looks neat? also why define i as Long instead of Integer?

Comment: `Long` is 32 bit, `Integer` is 16 bit.  On a 32 bit OS, long is faster, uses no more memory.  And number of rows can exceed max value of an Integer.  You can use an array if you want, and as I mentioned it will be faster for a lot of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The `Average()` function is a method of the `Excel.WorksheetFunction` object, not of any `Worksheet` object: `w_avg(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Average(...)`.

- Reference: [`WorksheetFunction` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301180%28v=office.15%29.aspx)